# Sieve of Eratos-thenes Prime Number Program

Tags: python

Alrighty so I have run into a snag with my coding when it comes to looping my code while `current < n`. This is an attempt at Sieve of Eratos-thenes. The code works one time around if I remove the while loop and the `intList[0] == current.`

```
intList = []
current = 2

def validNum ( n ):
    if n < 2:
        print ( "Your number must be more than 2. Try again." )
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

def getInput ():
    while 1:
        n = int ( input ( "Please enter a number more than 2: " ) )
        if validNum ( n ):
            return n + 1
            break

n = getInput ()
intList = list ( range ( 2, n ) )

#My poor attempt at a while loop.
while current < n:
    for x in intList:
        if x % current == 0:
            intList.remove ( x )
            #This is an attempt to update the current number to the lowest variable in the list
            intList[0] == current


print ( intList )
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Edit: I am learning now that there is much more wrong with my program than I thought. If my user Input is 10, the program should only keep 2, 3, 5, 7 within the intList.

Answer (score 0):

Your update is using the equality operator ==, and instead should be using the assignment operator =:

`current = intList[0]`

This will set the value of `current` to the first element in `intList`. There are still some other issues you need to solve, but that might get you rolling in the right direction.

Comment: That is a good step to fix my issue. I appreciate your time to respond!